# Two input files are setting to disabled at the same time

Tags: css, angularjs

Hi I am having two input files and after uploading the files they should be disabled individually.But with my below code  when itry to upload the first file both the file inputs get disabled at the same time.How to change the code to make it disable separately.

```
    angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.disabled = true;
      });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .ng-disabled {
        background: #E9B96E;
      }
    </style>

    <span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="file" ng-class="{'ng-disabled': disabled}" ng-disabled="disabled" id="input1" />
    <input type="file" ng-class="{'ng-disabled': disabled}" ng-disabled="disabled" id="input2"/>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same $scope variable for both fields, so it should be no surprise that both inputs react the same. Use separate $scope variables to fix this problem.

I could provide you a copy and paste solution, but I feel that if I let you look for the solution, now that you know the problem, you could learn a lot.